# Measurability of conditional distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be discrete random variables from $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ to  $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}^n)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathcal{B}^m)$ respectively.

Define $Q:\mathcal{B}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ as follows:

$Q(B,x)=\mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(B) \cap X^{-1}(x))/ \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(x))$ if $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(x))\neq 0$

$Q(B,x)=P(B)$ otherwise ($P$ is a probability on $(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathcal{B}^m)$

Now for fixed $B\in\mathcal{B}^m$, is the function $x\mapsto Q(B,x)$ measurable? If yes, how can I prove it? (my background in measure theory is very limited)

Thank you!

Comment: Is $B$ supposed to be fixed?

Comment: Yes, the function I'm studying is $f(x)=Q(B,x)$, given a fixed $B\in \mathcal{B}^m$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the function $f(x)=Q(B,x)$ is measurable.  There are only countably many values of $x$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(x))\neq 0$ (if there were uncountably many, then you could pick a countable collection such that the values $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(x))$ sum to more than $1$).  So, this function $f$ is just defined one way on some countable subset $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and is the constant function with value $P(B)$ on the rest of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This implies $f^{-1}(S)$ is either countable or cocountable for any set $S$ (since $f^{-1}(S)$ must either contain $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$ or be a subset of $C$).  Since any countable or cocountable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable, this means $f$ is measurable.

Comment: For the specific case $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}^n)$ can I justify "any countable or cocountable set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable" in the following way? If S is countable then it is the countable union of sets $\{x\}\in \mathcal{B}^n$, thus measurable. Otherwise $S^c$ is countable and so it is measurable.

Comment: That's correct.